# Gem::Specification.executables does not match that is created by `bundle gem` command

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm learning about how to make gem file.

By using `bundle gem foo`, I created a "hello world" gem.
If I specify the executable file name, it works fine.

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.executables   = "foo"
end
```

But as a default `Gem::Specification.executables` is set like this.

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
end
```

I thought this method find all files under the `bin` directory. But it doesn't work in my environment.

It's not a big matter to rewrite it every time I make a gem.
But I want to make it clear why this is not working for me.

My environments are:
ruby 2.0.0-p247 with rbenv,
bundle 1.3.5,
gem 2.0.3,
Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem as well. While seemingly intuitive, it doesn't appear to work for me at all. However, looking at other gems on GitHub, it looks like you can just specify the gem itself and the default /bin directory will be used

```
spec.executables = ['MyGem']
```

EDIT: Looking back at this, kevinrivers' answer is also valid. FYI Bundler does assume you're using git, so both answers work (amongst many more - in fact, after I posted this answer I soon dug more into how gemspecs work, especially related to the inclusion of files, and I wrote a lot about it, if you're interested - http://chrisarcand.com/using-git-in-your-gemspec/).

Answer (score 2):

The key line is right above spec.executables.

```
 spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
```

Git is being used to list files, if you haven't committed the addition of bin/, the file list will not have changed and thus your executable will not be built and added.